# Putting a transparent div on a map?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a actvity with a funcioando map. I want to put something like a transparent div to display information as the image.
The pallet in eclipse found the View element, view and ViewStub tried to use them but was not as I need. Can anyone help me figure out what element I use and how to make it transparent on the map?

[image: Model]

Comment: I think you will need to give some more information - is the view going on the map or is it a view above the map? If it is on the map (i.e. fixed to a point on the globe) take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions). If not your screenshot above shows a view above the map with (semi)transparency.

Comment: Use `FrameLayout` as the parent of the `Map` view. And add your Transparent view with normal `LinearLayout` with Horizontal direction below Map view inside FrameLayout.

Comment: I want to do exactly like the picture show the distance and time the route on the map with a transparent background. It is a fixed element on the map, the problem is that I do not know what element is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one `FrameLayout` and inside it put your google Map fragment and add your transparent layout into it.

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <include layout="@layout/top_menu_screen" />
      </FrameLayout>
```

For more details you can check out the `Google Map` demo which is provided inside the sdk of android inside folder `android sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/sample/maps` .

Just import that project into your workspace and check out the various functionality.

In that demo it had also shown the layering part on the map in the layout file `layer_demo.xml` which i am providing as below:
You can also create layer same way as you want by applying an image of some transparent color like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    <!-- A set of test checkboxes. -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/map"
        android:background="#D000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/layers_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/traffic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onTrafficToggled"
            android:text="@string/traffic" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/my_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onMyLocationToggled"
            android:text="@string/my_location" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/buildings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="onBuildingsToggled"
            android:text="@string/buildings" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/indoor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:onClick="onIndoorToggled"
            android:text="@string/indoor" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will guide you.

Thank you.